# Chef knife job start not displaying logs in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, knife

I am new to chef and installed push-jobs feature on chef-server to run commands from workstation or Jenkins.

When I run the command from Jenkins `knife job start 'chef-client' <node>`, it is not displaying complete log like when I run "chef-client" on a node.

How to get the complete log in Jenkins console ?? Please help me with this.

Below is the log which i am getting,

```
C:\chef\chef-repo>knife job start 'chef-client' hybris-server

Started.  Job ID: cdaf88e535736bbf816b1a46dd4c119d

.Running (1/1 in progress) ...
.......................Complete.

command:     chef-client

created_at:  Mon, 16 Jan 2017 11:48:37 GMT

env:

id:          cdaf88e535736bbf816b1a46dd4c119d

nodes:
  succeeded: hybris-server

run_timeout: 3600

status:      complete
updated_at:  Mon, 16 Jan 2017 11:49:25 GMT
```

Regards,
Umesha

Comment: Hi, this is resolved :).
solution : If you want the job output, you'll need to capture the Job ID and pass it into knife job output.

i was getting "ERROR: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)"
this [link] (https://github.com/chef/knife-push/issues/47) helped me to resolve above issue.

thankyou

Comment: Hi,

I am getting below error when i try to display output.

    `C:\chef\chef-repo>"knife.bat job output --channel stdout  cdaf88e5357385bb563083c2c29a9476 AT_Protogo"
    ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
    Response: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>  <BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested document was not found on  this server.<P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web  server</ADDRESS></BODY></HTML>`